# NSOperation and NSOperationQueue to perform task in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I want to program a  `NSOperationQueue`  to perform tasks on the other thread. 
So I created  `NSOperationQueue`  and class that derive from  `NSOperation` . I added there a protocol to know if the task finished without errors and so on. But if I add an instance in my other class and set the delegate there then the main thread waits for async task to exectute the delegate code. How to prevent from it. I want to do something in my app when the background task is running.

<kbd>AsyncTask.h</kbd>

```
@protocol AsyncTaskEventsProtocol <NSObject>

-(void)OnFinishedSuccess:(NSObject *)sender information:(NSString *)inf;
-(void)OnFinishedFailed:(NSObject *)sender information:(NSString *)inf exception:(NSException *) ex;

@end

@interface AsyncOperation : NSOperation
@property id<AsyncTaskEventsProtocol> delegate;
@end
```

<kbd>Async.m</kbd>

```
#import "AsyncOperation.h"

@implementation AsyncOperation
@synthesize delegate;

-(void)main{
    NSException * ex;
    @try {
            NSLog([NSThread isMainThread] ? @"This is the main thread" : @"This is not the main thread");
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        ex = exception;
    }

    if(delegate != nil)
    {
        if(ex == nil){
            [delegate OnFinishedSuccess:nil information:@"Data has been sent"];
        }
        else
        {
            [delegate OnFinishedFailed:nil information:@"Data has not been sent." exception:ex];
        }
     }

}
@end
```

In other class where create a queue

```
AsyncOperation * op = [[AsyncOperation alloc] init];
op.delegate = self;
NSOperationQueue * queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

[queue addOperation:op]
```

And the handler

```
-(void)OnFinishedSuccess:(NSObject *)sender information:(NSString *)inf
{
    UIAlertView * view = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Test" message:@"Message" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                          [view show];
}
```

Comment: Why you use `new` and `init`?

Comment: Oh... `new` is the same like `[[alloc]init]`

Comment: `new` is a shortcut for `alloc` and `init` calls. Also you have two problems in your code: 1. Use weak reference for delegate. 2. You must call any UI code only at UI thread so put your delegate calls on UI thread with GCD.

Comment: How should it looks like? 
`dispatch_async([NSOperationQueue mainQueue], ^{delegate code}`); ?

Comment: Can you show an excerpt of the interface definition of AsyncOperation? It's not clear to me that AsyncOperation is a subclass NSOperation nor why its being subclassed. Also, have you tried using the completionBlock property instead of a delegate?

Comment: I will be sending in NSOperation data to the database. There will be commands such as insert and update. What dou exactly mean by excerpt?